# localStorage.getItem retrieves 'null'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a counter for the number of times a button is pressed but when I try to retrieve it outside the function, it results in 'null' instead.

HTML:

```
<button class="signupbutton" onclick="counter()"> Yes I'm in!</button>
<div id="counter">
    <p>Number of people that have signed up for the newsletter: </p>
    <div id="counter1">0</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function counter() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('counter1');
    var count = localStorage.getItem('count');
    if (count == null) {
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
    localStorage.setItem('count', count);
    elem.innerHTML = count;
}
console.log(localStorage.getItem('count'));
var count1 = localStorage.getItem('count');
var elem = document.getElementById('counter1');
elem.innerHTML = count1;
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('count')` returns `null` if the key doesn’t exist. Once you set it within the `counter` function, it works fine.

Comment: Seems async issue

Comment: @OsmanGoniNahid Why would you assume so? There’s nothing asynchronous going on here.

Comment: You can simply replace all the code after the function with a function call `counter();`. The problem now is that the code after the function is evaluated before the function is ever called.

Comment: I am sure that localStorage for both get and set are async.

Comment: To test if the value is being stored and what value is set, open another tab with the same URL and add event listener for 'storage' event. You can see the demo in the examples section at [Mozzila web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: The value is only set when the eventhandler is executed, ie after you click on the button. The code below is executed when the script loads. Thus if `counter()` was not executed yet, the localstorage does not contain that key yet and `getItem` returns null.

Comment: @derpirscher So what would I have to do to get the counter() to load first and localStorage having that key so that I can display it?

Comment: @Xufox okay, now I get it why it doesn't work, but how would I go about getting the code to load first so localStorage would have that key of 'count'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your code a bit more DRY would save you a bit of time, in validating that your counter has a "real" value. For the rest, the `onclick` inside an html element is not encouraged anymore, you can just update your code like

```
// wait until the page has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // get your elements once
  const counterElement = document.querySelector('#counter1');
  const signupButton = document.querySelector('.signupbutton');

  // assign a click event to your button
  signupButton.addEventListener('click', updateCounter);

  // function to retrieve the counter from your localStorage
  function getKeyOrDefault( key, defaultValue = 0 ) {
    return localStorage.getItem( key ) || defaultValue;
  }

  function updateCounter( e ) {
    let counter = parseInt( getKeyOrDefault( 'counter' ) );
    counter++;
    counterElement.innerHTML = counter;
    localStorage.setItem( 'counter', counter );
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  // set the initial value
  counterElement.innerHTML = getKeyOrDefault( 'counter' );
} );
```

Ofcourse, don't forget to change your html, to remove the counter function from the html element like

```
<button class="signupbutton"> Yes I'm in!</button>
<div id="counter">
    <p>Number of people that have signed up for the newsletter: </p>
    <div id="counter1">0</div>
</div>
```

A sample of this code can be found on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16hz75fw/2/) (it is not here, as stackoverflow doesn't support localstorage)

Now, the only thing I am really worried about, is the text of your HTML, note that the localStorage will be a personal storage for all clients, so, if this is a website run from the internet, all persons who arrive there once will start with null (or 0) and just increase by 1 each time they click the button, you will be none the wiser, as it is localStorage.

Ofcourse, if you handle it on 1 computer, where people have to input their data, then you have at least some data stored locally, but still, this isn't a real storage you can do something with ;)

Comment: Ah! I see, thank you so much! That solved my problem! And yes, for this localStorage it's just for demo purposes to show that it works as we're only using it on one device.

Answer (score 0):

The code does work. However, you have to make sure, that the `counter` function is interpreted before the page has loaded. Put the JS at the end of the document `head`, or rewrite the onlick using `addEventListener`.

Comment: The order doesn’t make a huge difference here. The important part is that `counter` is global, if `onclick` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert to integer ..

```
function counter() {
var elem = document.getElementById('counter1');
var count = localStorage.getItem('count');
if (count == null) {
    count = 0;
}
count = parseInt(count);
count++;
localStorage.setItem('count', count);
elem.innerHTML = count;
}
console.log(localStorage.getItem('count'));
var count1 = localStorage.getItem('count');
var elem = document.getElementById('counter1');
elem.innerHTML = count1;
```

**Please Try again**

Comment: That's wrong. Local storage will always save as string and get will always return a string. Regardless of the type passed to set.

Answer (score 0):

getItem/setItem are unavailable until didFinish will have executed unless
[Read local storage data using WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838909/read-local-storage-data-using-wkwebview)