# Read local storage data using WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I need to read value stored in the local storage of WKWbview. 
I tried using the below code but getting nil. 
I am able to write values in local storage but facing difficulty in reading values from it.

```
  let script = "localStorage.getItem('token')"
        wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (token, error) in
            print("token = \(token)")
        }
```

WKWebView init code:

```
    // 1
    let accessToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token") as? String
    // 2
    let refreshToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "RefreshToken") as? String
    // 3
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    // 4
    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    let accessTokenScript = "javascript: localStorage.setItem('token', '\(accessToken!)')"
    // 5
    let userAccessTokenScript = WKUserScript(source: accessTokenScript, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)

    // 6
    contentController.addUserScript(userAccessTokenScript)
    configuration.userContentController = contentController
    self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: controller.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: Try this javascript code: ```"localStorage.getItem(\"token\")"```

Comment: You need to call this script in ```didFinish navigation```. When do you inject it?

Comment: Its injected at document start and updated by the website every 15mins.

Comment: I am talking about the script for getting the token, not when you set it. This one: ```"localStorage.getItem(\"token\")"```

Comment: I guess the mistake was i was calling getItem before didfinish navigation getting called. Thanks your suggestion was helpful in fixing this.

Comment: I will write an answer for that, so you could mark as answered, and others might see the solution in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to inject this script when the website has already loaded:

- your WKWebView needs to assign the `navigationDelegate`

  `webView.navigationDelegate = self`
- inject the script when the website was loaded completely

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    
    //you might want to edit the script, with the escape characters
    let script = "localStorage.getItem(\"token\")"
    wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (token, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print ("localStorage.getitem('token') failed due to \(error)")
            assertionFailure()
        }
        print("token = \(token)")
    }
}
```

Comment: does setItem fails for the same reason? token needs to be set in storage before the page starts to load

Comment: @AntonTropashko check what the author wrote on the lines #4 & #5 in his code. That is when you write the `setItem`, and also very important `injectionTime: .atDocumentStart`.